# visibility of FormController

Tags: angularjs

I understand that [each form directive creates an instance of FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) that can be published onto the current scope under the form's name. Based on what I understand about Angular controllers (namely that they 'attach' to the DOM element on which they are defined) I would expect the `myForm` FormController to not be visible outside the `<form>` element, just like the `ctl` MyFormController is not visible outside the `<div>` element.

Yet the `myForm` object **is** visible outside the `<form>` whereas the `ctl` object, is (as expected) not visible outside the `<div>`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='theApp'>
    <div ng-controller='MyFormController as ctl' >
      <form name='myForm' novalidate>
        Name:<input type='text' ng-model='ctl.name'/>
      </form>
      myForm is visible: {{myForm}}
    </div>
    ctl is not visible: {{ctl}}
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     var theApp = angular.module('theApp', []);
     theApp.controller('MyFormController', [function() {}]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `ng-controller` is on the body tag, and the `{{ctl.report(myForm)}}` is contained within that HTML element.  What's the confusion?

Comment: @ryanyuyu I understand that a https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController is created for every `form` directive. In my case this controller is available under the name `myForm`. I was expecting `myForm` to be visible only within the `<form>` element on which the `FormController` is attached.

Comment: Ah my bad.  I've not worked on anything at this minute level of detail.

Comment: Why? myForm is a new controller attached to the current scope which MyFormController.

Comment: @sirrocco OK, so the new controller is visible beyond the end of the element on which it is declared because it's available as a property of the MyFormController onto which it was 'published'? Yet, in the expression it is accessed simply as `myForm`, not as `ctl.myForm`. I am sort-of expecting the myForm controller to not be in the lexical scope or be garbage-collected (figure of speech) outside of the `<form>` element.

Comment: Well it's a property of the scope. `ctl` is also on the `scope`: it's the instance of `MyFormController` attached to the `scope`. That's probably where the confusion comes from: `ctl` is not equivalent to the current scope.

Comment: Maybe it's more complex than that, see updated example which is more minimal. Based on further testing it appears that the controller created by the framework for the `form` is attached on the parent element of the form whereas the controller I create using the `ng-controller` directive is attached on the element on which it is declared. `myForm` is indeed visible outside the `<form>` but not outside the `<div>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give it another go in an answer. I'll add comments in the html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='theApp'>
<!--Ok, app initialized, $rootScope is initialized -->
    <div ng-controller='MyFormController as ctl' >
<!--New controller - let's give it a child scope: $myFormScope = $rootScope.$new() -->
<!--Set ctl on $myFormScope, access it via $myFormScope.ctl -->
      <form name='myForm' novalidate>
<!--Create myFormController, attach it to $myFormScope (the current scope), access it via $myFormScope.myForm -->
        Name:<input type='text' ng-model='ctl.name'/>
      </form>
      myForm is visible: {{myForm}}
<!--it's visible because we're essentially accessing $myFormScope.myForm -->
    </div>
    ctl is not visible: {{ctl}}
<!--it's NOT visible because we're accessing $rootScope.ctl but ctl is not on $rootScope -->
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     var theApp = angular.module('theApp', []);
     theApp.controller('MyFormController', [function() {}]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope it makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

The `form` directive does not create a new scope and the form controller is published onto the current scope under the value of the `name` attribute:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

Instead, the `ng-controller` directive always creates a new scope. That's why the form controller is visible outside the <form> element and within the scope of the `MyFormController` (as it was published on its scope), whereas the `MyFormController` is not visible outside the <div> element.

Another caveat is that in addition to the form controller created on the current scope, there's also the form DOM object that's created on the global window object (the form controller shadows the form DOM object as both of them use the value of the `name` attribute of the form element as their name).

The following code demonstrates the above:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <script src='angular.js'</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     Object.prototype.asdf2343_getName = function() { 
       var funcNameRegex = /function (.{1,})\(/;
       var results = (funcNameRegex).exec((this).constructor.toString());
       return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : "";
     };
    </script>
    <div ng-app = 'theApp'>
      <div ng-controller='theController as ctl'>
        {{ctl.showScopes()}}
        <form name='form1' novalidate>
        </form>
        {{ctl.log(form1)}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     angular.module('theApp', [])
            .controller('theController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope){
              this.log = function(x) {
                console.log('x is the form1 on the window object? '+(x===window.form1));
                console.log('the type of window.form1 is: '+window.form1.asdf2343_getName());
                console.log('x is the form1 object in scope? '+(x===$scope.form1));
                console.log('the type of $scope.form1 is: '+$scope.form1.asdf2343_getName());
              };
              this.showScopes = function () {
                for (p in $rootScope) {
                  if ($rootScope[p]===$scope)
                    console.log('$scope found in $rootScope as property named: ['+p+']');
                }
              };
            }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Didn't I say the same thing ? Anyhow, I'm glad you got it sorted out :)